# How to fix error Kohana_Exception [ 0 ]: The type property does not exist in the Model_Emails class

Tags: php, sql, kohana

i change column name in db (type in type_id) and now i can't complete request. In code I do not specify any columns, why kohana search this property "type".

```
public static function getEmails()
{
    return ( new self)
        ->find_all()
        ->as_array();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Without full Model code I can only tell you, that this [error is raised](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide-api/ORM#get) (end function), because ORM, can't find this value in self or related tables. Find in your model similar code:

```
class Model_Many extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
        'title'=> array('model' => 'Title', 'foreign_key' => 'title_id'),
    )

    protected $_table_columns = Array(
        'many_id' => FALSE,
        'title_id' => FALSE,
    );
}
```

`$_table_columns` contains your table structure. If you don't have this, then remove cache on server (`APPATH/cache`).

For relations I highly recommend reading [this](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide/orm/relationships).

BTW: ORM for getting arrays isn't recommended. It is slow and consumes many memory. Better use [query builder](https://docs.koseven.ga/guide/database/query/builder).